# How to define several typescript compile tasks in one tasks.json?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I am trying to define different build tasks for my typescript project in VS Code. My tasks.json works as long as there is only one task.

tasks.json (command pallette > task tsc)

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "tsc",
"showOutput": "silent",
"args": ["-p", "."],
"problemMatcher": "$tsc"
"isShellCommand": true
}
```

When I define several tasks, I can select them from the command palette, but they generate the following error:

*TS5042: Option 'project' cannot be mixed with source files on a command line*

tasks.json (command pallette > task dosomething)

```
{
"version": "0.1.0",
"command": "tsc",
"isShellCommand": true,
"tasks":[
    {
        "taskName":"dosomething",
        "showOutput": "silent",
        "args": ["-p", "."],
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    },
    {
        "taskName":"compileandwatch",
        "showOutput": "silent",
        "args": ["-p", ".", "-w"],
        "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
    }
]
}
```

Question: how to define several tasks in tasks.json? Which parameters should be included in "tasks" and which should be in the root? There is no example in the [microsoft docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/languages/typescript).

I tried leaving "args" empty:

```
"args": [],
```

But then I get this error **"dosomething.ts"** not found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to set `suppressTaskName = true` on each task. Below is an example of tasks.json that works for me. Note that this way the `args` define both what should be run and what parameters passed to it, task name does not affect resulting command:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "node",
    "windows": {
        "command": "node.exe"
    },
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build.dev",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js", "build.dev"],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "problemMatcher": [
                "$tsc"
            ]
        },
        {
            "taskName": "document.code",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js", "document.code"],
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "problemMatcher": []
        },
        {
            "taskName": "start.specs.web.server",
            "args": ["${workspaceRoot}/node_modules/http-server/bin/http-server",
                    "${workspaceRoot}/dist/dev/specs"],
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "problemMatcher": []
        }        
    ]
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. But what does "suppressTaskName" do? Why would I want to suppress the task name?

Comment: task name will not be used to specify program name to be run. So when you have task with name `dosomething` vscode will not try to run  `node dosomething ../../../gulp.js ...` plus arguments from `args`. Instead it will construct command using only arguments. See my sample config - `build.dev` task will run `node ../../../gulp.js ...`

Comment: Thanks. This works, although it depends on having node to actually execute those commands. It seems there is no way to have completely different commands inside tasks.json (for example, a node-sass compile command, and a tsc compile command)

Comment: Thank you for this!! Why the hell does it insert the taskname into the command?! If I wanted an extra parameter I would have put it in the `args` list! Either way thanks @Amid!