# How to both build and compile typescript with tasks.json

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, asp.net-core, visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code (vscode) and this is an asp.net core project that was initialized in Visual Studio 2015 (VS Proper). When I got it set up in vscode the initial process included adding this auto-generated build task inside tasks.json:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\project.json"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        }
    ]
}
```

But I'm using typescript so I want it to compile. I type "Configure Task Runner" into the command pallet (only after renaming tasks.json since it creates a file of the same name) and configure the typescript task which looks like this:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "tsc",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": ["-p", "."],
    "showOutput": "silent",
    "problemMatcher": "$tsc"
}
```

Then when I build, my typescript is nicely compiled but I don't get an actual "build"...

The intiuitive solution that does NOT work:

```
{
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "command": "dotnet",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "build",
            "args": [
                "${workspaceRoot}\\project.json"
            ],
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "tsc",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "args": ["-p", "."],
            "showOutput": "silent",
            "problemMatcher": "$tsc"

        }
    ]
}
```

How can I get both processes to happen upon each build?
Promising links that didn't help me:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/981

[How to define several typescript compile tasks in one tasks.json?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36451886/how-to-define-several-typescript-compile-tasks-in-one-tasks-json)

Answer (score 0):

This feature request is still opened, see: https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/981.

The best way to solve this is to use a task runner like grunt, gulp or even npm to run your different tasks. In the tasks.json you can then define the build and test commands by taskname and setting the problemmatcher per task.

Comment: Hmm... I've already scanned over issue/981 a couple times but it's a bit overwhelming. Would you be able to link to a related S/O question that is answered with the gulp solution or even provide a brief example? I'm a bit new to all this and not really sure how magic strings like { "taskName": "tsc" } and { "args": ["-p", "."] } end up calling my typescript compiler, nor how to go about replicating this action on-build (better yet on-save) via gulp. I am mildly familiar with gulp though, which is why that would be my preference. You can do this with npm? Really anything...

Answer (score 0):

### [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) solved this issue in the [tasks.json `v2.0.0`](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks) release.

---

The solution is the ["dependsOn"](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks) property, and it adds another task as a dependency to a parent task. The `"dependsOn"` property is added to the parent task, and takes an array that contains the name, (or `"labels"`) of all the tasks you wish to assign as its dependents.

I use it to automate the build systems for my NPM packages I maintain. With dependsOn, I find `tasks.json` to be a far better tool for automating than GULP, or other task frameworks.

###### A tasks that executes 2 tasks as a single task can be configured using the example below:

---

**Say that the Following is True:** You defined a task in your "tasks.json" file named `"Build Software"`, and a task named `"Execute Software's Tests"`. You want one to run after the other, but you don't want to have to execute each one manually, you want to instantiate a single task, but have both task execute. The solution (as I stated above) is "dependsOn", the task in your tasks.json will look like this:

```
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "dependsOn": ["Build Software", "Execute Software's Tests"]
    }
```

Notice that the `"dependsOn"` property, with the use of the `"label"` property are enough to define a task?

##### There is an issue though:

The above 2-property task definition will execute the task Asynchronously, however, we don't want to execute are tests before updated tests have even finished building, as a consequence, are new configuration will look like this:

```
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "dependsOn": ["Build Software", "Execute Software's Tests"],
      "dependsOrder": "sequence"
    }
```

The newly added **`"dependsOrder": "sequence"`** K/V pair configures the task to run its dependents one after the next, the order in which it executes the tasks is the order in-which they are assigned to the `"dependsOn"` array, in other words the order looks like this:

"dependsOn": ["fist", "second", "last"]

If you want your tasks to run as preformant as possible, and synchronicity is not required, then you can just omit the "dependsOrder" property from your configuration, and your tasks will be handed to V8's asynchronous loop, which will decide how to best execute the instructions that you gave it.

For more, click on the links above. The most helpful link above is [this one](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_compound-tasks)